# Github: Problems after merge-conflicts

Tags: git, github

I had to work a bit on our project offline and wanted to sync my commits later on. Of course there had to be some merge conflicts which I resolved. But even after resolving there was the error message "cannot create new commit" and git told me to view the log.

The log told me that there were conflicts left (which I already had resolved) and that was all I could read from the logfile.

Well... I closed GitHub and now that I opened it again every file in our project apears to be deleted and added again... or added and added again.

What can I do to make GitHub work again?

[image: Screenshot of GitHub]

Answer (score 0):

After You merge conflicts you need to **add** conflicted file to mark you resolved them.
Then you can commit to sync to server

Comment: And how can I resolve the curret problem? (seen in the screenshot)

Comment: I think you should reset to your commit before you pull from server then pull again